# Reading UISegmentedControl's identity

Tags: iphone

I have an `UITableView` with about 30 custom cells each containing an `UISegmentedControl`. I have wired up the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event to get hold of `selectedIndex`.

I would also like to get hold of `UISegmentedControl`'s identity to identify it among the 30 `UISegmentedControls`.

So, how can I get hold of the identity for the current `UISegmentedControl` that triggered the event? I have not found an "id" or "name" property for `UISegmentedControl`.

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the tag property of the UISegmentedControl. You can set this to an integer (in your case, probably 1-30), and access it from the UIControlEventValueChanged action.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, it worked. I come from .NET background and I thought if there was a Tag-property at Apple-world too....I didn't find it from the Documentation, so I'd better practice my documentation reading skills. =)